# Legendary plans location (in RoS)

Tags: diablo-iii

I was wondering, as I'd really want to get my hands on the Plan for the "Cosmic Strand" legendray item, is there any particular location/bosses where one can found the plan for a particular legendary item? Or are all the plan dropped anywhere at random?

Comment: I do not have any definitive answer, but I believe legendary items and plans are more constrained by difficulty than location. Certain items will not drop unless you play on Torment difficulty, with a better chance on higher Torments.